# Dynamic Editing of form action path

Tags: javascript

I want to edit the form action url dynamically.my current code is like

```
    function Fbsubmit()
      {
    var cont=document.getElementById("viewcontent").value;
    var title=document.getElementById("noteheadid").value;
    var loc='http://122.98.15.171/xyx/phptest.php'+'?title='+title+'&cont='+cont;
    location.href=loc;
      }
```

here the problem is that user will be able to change the url while its loading the page.Can anyone suggest way to convert it as a post method

Answer (score 0):

Change the form `method` attribute dynamically using the `setAttribute()` method as :

`document.getElementById("myForm").setAttribute("method", "post");`

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery is OK, you can do it as easily as:

```
$.post('http://122.98.15.171/xyx/phptest.php',
    {
        title: $('#noteheadid').val(),
        cont: $('#viewcontent').val(),
    }
);
```

**NOTE**: You don't *need* jQuery to do the above. It just makes it easy and more readable.